# apply code to multiple control fields

Tags: ms-access

I am using code the code below to change the property of a combo box and a label. i have another 40 combo boxes and labels(combo2, combo3, combo4 ..........). Is there a way i could reuse the code instead of copying the code and having to change the name for each combo box and label manually.

```
If (Combo1 = 1) Then
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "255"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "POOR"
ElseIf (Combo1 = 2) Then
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "2895086"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "FAIR"
ElseIf (Combo1 = 3) Then
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "35584"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "GOOD"
ElseIf (Combo1 = 4) Then
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "52480"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "VERY GOOD"
ElseIf (Combo1 = 5) Then
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "64636"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, "EXCELLENT"
Else
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Combo1", acPropertyBackColor, "16579836"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "Label1", acPropertyCaption, ","
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub procedure that receives as arguments the combo1 integer value and the ComboBox and Listbox controls. The procedure would look something like following:

```
Public Sub SetupProperties(combo1 As Integer, ChangeComboBox As Access.ComboBox, ChangeLabel As Access.Label)

Dim longBackColour As Long
Dim stringCaption As String
' set up  background colour and caption
If (combo1 = 1) Then
    longBackColour = 255
    stringCaption = "POOR"
ElseIf (combo1 = 2) Then
    longBackColour = 2895086
    stringCaption = "FAIR"
ElseIf (combo1 = 3) Then ' and so on...

End If
' Change properties of the controls
ChangeComboBox.BackColor = longBackColour
ChangeLabel.Caption = stringCaption
```

End Sub

Then call the procedure from within a loop as follows:

```
Dim combo1 As Integer
combo1 = 1
Dim integerCounter As Integer
For integerCounter = 1 To 40
    SetupProperties combo1, Me.Controls("Combo" & Trim(CStr(integerCounter))), Me.Controls("Label" & Trim(CStr(integerCounter)))
Next
```